# Расстановка запятых и точек

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Любой человек может вернуться когда ему захочется а снимать с него донат вообще ужасно*

Answer (score 3):

Можно оформить так:

***Любой человек может вернуться, когда ему захочется, а снимать с него донат – вообще ужасно.***

1. Первая запятая отделяет придаточное предложение условия (союз ***когда*** в значении ***если***).

Есть, конечно, вариант не ставить эту запятую по правилу о [**цельных по смыслу выражениях**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146) типа *"приходить когда вздумается", "приходи когда хочешь"* (Розенталь): ***Любой человек может вернуться когда ему захочется*** (то есть в любой момент).

Выбор зависит от контекста, структуры предложения, интонации и от того, какой смысл вкладывается автором.

2. Перед союзом ***а*** всегда ставится запятая. (Можно поставить и точку, разделяя предложение на два.)
3. В последней части лучше поставить тире между подлежащим (***снимать***) и сказуемым (***ужасно***), тем самым графически обозначить паузу и показать, к какому слову относится ***вообще***.

> При наличии паузы между главными членами предложения **тире** ставится между подлежащим, выраженным неопределенной формой глагола, и сказуемым, выраженным предикативным наречием на ***-о*** (категорией состояния): ***Уступить — позорно*** (Тендр.)... (Розенталь. [**Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92).)

4. В конце предложения ставится **точка** (если нужно – восклицательный знак).